# MacOs Catalina 10.15.5 crashes and report gives no clue

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, macos-catalina

I recently updated my MacOs from Catalina 10.15.4 to 10.15.5 (19F101).
I use Android Studio as IDE to develop Android apps using Java programming language.
So I also updated Android Studio to v4.0 and Java to 8u251.

I never faced this error before, but, now I get the system crashed at least once per day. I can't understand what caused the crash from the report details below, I only see the word java :

```html
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801524aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f980dfbcb, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x00000001ca6f90e2, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x013050217a000004, RBX: 0xffffff802dd55800, RCX: 0x000024980000000a, RDX: 0xffffff8104098000
RSP: 0xffffff9149053930, RBP: 0xffffff9149053960, RSI: 0x000000000000000a, RDI: 0xffffff802a335000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000020000011000, R11: 0x0000000001a8000e
R12: 0xffffff81076f6030, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff802dd55e50, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f980dfbcb, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9149053390 : 0xffffff801511f5cd 
0xffffff91490533e0 : 0xffffff8015258b05 
0xffffff9149053420 : 0xffffff801524a68e 
0xffffff9149053470 : 0xffffff80150c5a40 
0xffffff9149053490 : 0xffffff801511ec97 
0xffffff9149053590 : 0xffffff801511f087 
0xffffff91490535e0 : 0xffffff80158c27cc 
0xffffff9149053650 : 0xffffff801524aa3a 
0xffffff91490537d0 : 0xffffff801524a738 
0xffffff9149053820 : 0xffffff80150c5a40 
0xffffff9149053840 : 0xffffff7f980dfbcb 
0xffffff9149053960 : 0xffffff7f97c2151e 
0xffffff91490539a0 : 0xffffff7f97c21a4f 
0xffffff91490539d0 : 0xffffff7f97c3067d 
0xffffff9149053a10 : 0xffffff7f980e5bdc 
0xffffff9149053a40 : 0xffffff7f97c1f00b 
0xffffff9149053ac0 : 0xffffff801585695e 
0xffffff9149053b10 : 0xffffff8015854be7 
0xffffff9149053b60 : 0xffffff801585dcb3 
0xffffff9149053ca0 : 0xffffff80152082b2 
0xffffff9149053db0 : 0xffffff8015125328 
0xffffff9149053e10 : 0xffffff80150fbcc5 
0xffffff9149053e70 : 0xffffff8015112aa2 
0xffffff9149053f00 : 0xffffff8015230d05 
0xffffff9149053fa0 : 0xffffff80150c6226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f97c18000->0xffffff7f97cdcfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E35D090D-DB9E-3DD0-9723-651FA730AA13]@0xffffff7f961d6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f95b31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f96613000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f96529000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[1FB49168-0280-3F04-A99A-F830C915E994]@0xffffff7f95f05000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics(14.0.6)[6139D437-2098-316E-967B-4692BAA82C5B]@0xffffff7f98098000->0xffffff7f98131fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f95b31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f96613000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f96529000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f97c18000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: java

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014f00000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 28462843245396
last loaded kext at 21798979754283: >usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f98b51000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v061000 6.10.0
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm 7.5.1
>!AMikeyHIDDriver 131
@fileutil 20.036.15
>AudioAUUC 1.70
|IO!BSerialManager 7.0.5f6
>!APlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0
>AGPM 111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim 1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.8
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver 283.15
>!AHDA 283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 5.2.4
>!AHV 1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>pmtelemetry 1
>AGDCBacklightControl 5.2.4
>!A!IBDWGraphics 14.0.6
>!ABacklight 180.3
>eficheck 1
>!ACameraInterface 7.6.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP 3.1.4
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl 1.14
>!ASMCLMU 212
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport 7.0.5f6
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!ALPC 3.1
>!AFIVRDriver 4.1.0
|IO!BUSBDFU 7.0.5f6
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
>!U!SCoexistentDriver 489.120.1
>!UCardReader 489.120.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO 1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext 522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
@BootCache 40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs 1412.120.2
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver 3430.1
@private.KextAudit 1.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC 1400.1.1
>!ASmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>!ARTC 2.0
>!AACPIButtons 6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS 2.1
>!AACPIEC 6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4 1
@nke.applicationfirewall 303
$TMSafetyNet 8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity 1
>usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm 5.0.0
@kext.triggers 1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl 5.2.4
|IOAVB!F 850.1
>!ASSE 1.0
>!ABacklightExpert 1.1.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink 4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter 6.2.6
@!AGPUWrangler 5.2.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F 1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C 1.0.18d1
>X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport 576.1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport 7.0.5f6
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl 5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2 438.5.4
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHDA!C 283.15
|IOGraphics!F 576.1
|IOHDA!F 283.15
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C 1.1.0
>usb.!UHub 1.2
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
|IOUSBMass!SClass 4.0.4
>!UAudio 323.1
>usb.cdc 5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice 1.2
|IOAudio!F 300.2
@vecLib.kext 1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface 269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme 3
|IOAHCIBlock!S 316.100.5
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter 6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F 6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.5.4
|IOAHCI!F 290.0.1
>!AActuatorDriver 3440.1
>!AHIDKeyboard 209
>!AHS!BDriver 3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver 7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger 7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport 3440.8
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver 59
>!AThunderboltNHI 5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F 7.6.1
|IO80211!F 1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
>corecapture 1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F 1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F 900.4.2
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime 2.1
|IOSMBus!F 1.1
|IOHID!F 2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox 300.0
@kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore 28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM 489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager 1.0
>KernelRelayHost 1
>!ASEPManager 1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor 1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver 157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F 422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F 1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties 1.2
>usb.!UCommon 1.0
>!ABusPower!C 1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F 1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F 840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC 3.1.9
>watchdog 1
|IOPCI!F 2.9
|IOACPI!F 1.4
@kec.pthread 1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It happens randomly when I run a Java application but it seems to happen more when I do something with Netbeans or Maven.

Comment: I started using a virtual memory cleaner called "CleanMyMac" free version to clean my RAM at least once per hour, and my mac rarely crashes (once during last 2 weeks).

Comment: I have same problem and can't understand the cause too. Catalina 10.15.5, AndroidStudio 4.1-RC1 One difference is thread name: BSD process name corresponding to current thread: studio

Comment: Same issue with current thread: idea

Comment: Same issue with current thread: safari

Comment: The same issue with me, whenever there are multiple applications running it suddenly hangs. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try to update your system to BigSur, the error never occurred to me while using BigSur. I think that the problem is somehow linked to the RAM memory especially if the Mac is equipped with only 8Gb. And as you all know, you can't upgrade it to 16Gb or more, Apple wants you to buy a new Mac instead.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel panics are predominately caused by third-party kernel extensions or hardware faults.

A Page Fault is memory related, so it may be your RAM. [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) or [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) can be used to check the RAM.

Resetting NVRAM may fix some rare causes of panics.

If you have any external hardware connected to the Mac, that could also cause a panic. If you have anything other than keyboard/mouse/printer connected, disconnect them and see if the panics stop.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251609637?answerId=253103012022#253103012022

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I stopped using Mac, I am back using an Asus Laptop with windows 10.

Comment: Ahh too bad it didn’t work for you! Maybe something in your machine itself was faulty. I’m happy I don’t face this problem. I gotta say that I like to code way more on a Mac than on a Windows machine (I code on both). Anyway, good luck!